# Remove a specific cookie from all request ctx koa?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

What is the most effective way for remove a cookie from every request / reponse on node.js with koa ?
I want to remove it everywhere, even on ctx.req , ctx.query etc , everything he would appears.

i tried with

```
ctx.cookies.set('foo', null);
```

but it's still exist on ctx.req ?

```
router.get("/", async ctx => {

      ctx.cookies.set('foo', null);
   
      ctx.redirect(`/auth`);
      await handleRequest(ctx);
    }
  });
```